# Form Validation for Dynamically added and removed form Elements

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form element in which I can add and remove value dynamically.

For example in the below code domain can be added and removed using addDomain and removeDomain

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of company.domains">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ngControl="domainC"  [(ngModel)]="company.domains[i]">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 pull-left">
                            <a (click)="removeDomain(i)"> <i  class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            <a (click)="addDomain()"> <i  class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I need to validate these on submit since all added values are required. I am working with Control in angular 2, but unable to figure out how to apply validation to such elements, Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jGlfbiWuPXRWMjRZ8pfO?p=preview)

You can bind the form to a form model

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let item of controls let idx=index">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <label>{{item.name}}</label><input type="text" class="form-control" [ngControl]="item.name"  [(ngModel)]="values[item.name]">
        {{item.control.errors | json}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 pull-left">
        <div><button (click)="removeDomain(i)">remove</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div>
  <label>control name</label><input #nameInput>
  <label>validator</label><select #validatorInput>
    <option>required</option>
    <option>minLength</option>
    <option>maxLength</option>
  </select>
  <label>length</label><input type="number" #lengthInput>
  <button (click)="addDomain(nameInput.value, validatorInput.value, lengthInput.value)">add</button>
</div>
```

```
export class App {
  form:ControlGroup;
  controls [
    { name: 'name', control: new Control('', Validators.required) },
    { name: 'password', control: new Control('', Validators.minLength(3))}
  ];
  values = {
    name: '',
    password: '',
  }

  constructor(fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group();
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
    this.controls.map((item) => {
      console.log('map item', item);
      this.form.addControl(item.name, item.control);
    });
  }

  removeDomain(i) {
    this.values[this.controls[i].name]=undefined;
    this.form.removeControl(this.controls[i].name);
    this.controls.splice(i);
    this.form.controls.forEach(c => c.updateValueAndValidity());
  }

  addDomain(name, validator, length) {
    this.values[name] = '';
    var validator;
    if(length) {
      validator = Validators[validator](length);
    } else {
      validator = Validators[validator];
    }

    let newCtl = new Control('', validator);
    this.controls.push({name: name, control: newCtl});
    this.form.addControl(name, newCtl);
    //this.controls.forEach(c => this.form.controls[c.name].updateValueAndValidity());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. The issue was related to the naming of control. When a row was removed from the middle, the table index gets reinitiated and adding another row with duplicate control name.

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/S1aAuW?p=preview)

Added a counter that always increments and assigned it to detail object.

```
addRow() {
    this.details.push(<IDetail>{controlIndex:this.iRow});

    this.rowValidateForm(this.iRow++, 'add');        
}
```

On remove get the counter from the detail object and remove controls from the group with the counter name.

```
removeRow(index) {
  let controlIndex = this.details[index].controlIndex;

  this.details.splice(index, 1);
  this.rowValidateForm(controlIndex, 'remove');
}
```

In view replace the row index in FormControlName with the countrolIndex.

Comment: how to set `Validators.required` dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the validation programmatically in your view controller, you could reference your control in your view and pass it to the controller on change. Something like:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ngControl="domainC"  #domainCControl="ngForm" [(ngModel)]="company.domains[i]" (change)="onDomainInputChanged(domainCControl)">
 <div [hidden]="domainCControl.valid">Control invalid</div>
```

controller:

```
onDomainInputChanged(control: NgControlName) {
  // You have access to control.control.validatorFn here
}
```

But you probably want to implement the validator in a dedicated directive you could reuse elsewhere:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ngControl="domainC"  [(ngModel)]="company.domains[i]" validate-domain-control >
```

And the directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[validate-domain-control][ngControl],[validate-domain-control][ngModel],[validate-domain-control][ngFormControl]',
    providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(()=>DomainValidator), multi: true}]
})
export class DomainValidator implements Validator {

    constructor() {}

    validate(control:AbstractControl) {
        if (isValid(control.value)) {
           return null;
        }
        return {'myValidityClass': false};
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the html validation attributes like `required`, `min-length="3"`, etc... which are already handled by angular.